# Should Squid honor no-cache and s-maxage in reverse proxy mode?

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy, cache, http-headers

I'm using Squid 2.7.STABLE9, which I compiled from source.

My understanding of `no-cache` is that the cache must revalidate with the origin server before serving up a cached copy of the resource, and that this takes place with an If-Modified-Since header.

My understanding of `s-maxage` is that a shared cache/proxy should consider the resource fresh for the given number of seconds.

My expectation is that `Cache-Control: no-cache, s-maxage=300` should trigger Squid to consider the resource fresh for 5 minutes and it should revalidate with the origin server before serving the cached version.

Am I understanding the usage of these headers correctly?  If so, should I expect this behavior Squid to carry out this behavior when configured as a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

In your example the no-cache entry does not specify a field name, so this section applies:

> **no-cache**
>       If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a cache
>   MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a
>   subsequent request without successful
>   revalidation with the origin server.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1